# What is a photography portfolio, and when would I use it?

Tags: business, portfolio

I hear people talk about 'building their photography portfolio.' What is a photography portfolio, and when would I use it?

Comment: How odd that somebody with so many points should not know. I smell boosting.

Comment: Grasshopper, just because *I* know the answer to the question, does not mean it isn't valuable to *ask* the question. When you can snatch this pebble out of my hand, then you will be ready to be a photographer. ;-)

Comment: In any case, at this point rep-wise I'm well beyond the need for 'boosting,' but I do think the site is tilted heavily in favor of 'tech related' questions, so if I see an opportunity to add a few questions to the 'art' and 'business' sides of photography, I tend to take 'em.

Comment: I rather link @JayLancePhotography's questions, even if he does clearly know the answers to many of them;-)

Comment: *boosting* - LOL!

Comment: I'll be honest with y'all that I'm not *completely* sure what 'boosting' is. I get the sense from @time4tea's original comment that 'boosting' has to do with asking questions you already know the answer to, and if that's the case... Guilty. But being as our FAQ clearly indicates that it's OK to ask and answer your own questions then logically, asking questions you know the answer to is quite alright around here as well. @time4tea's comment makes me think that this would be frowned upon in other communities... and it makes me glad that I'm here, and not wherever @time4tea comes from. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I think it means "asking questions you already know the answer to"... in order to collect reps for providing a good answer. Evidently, you did not answer yourself, so you can't be blamed for that ;-)

Comment: On this question at least. :-)

Comment: If asking a good question is "boosting" then so is providing a good answer to a question.  Both contribute positively to the quality and amount of content on the site.

Comment: @time4tea: I've created a thread over on Meta where we're discussing some of the differences between photo-SE and SO. It's here: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/754/do-we-need-to-clarify-that-photo-se-best-practices-may-be-different-than-those if you feel like weighing in...

Comment: Hmm... I would never have asked this question, yet the "winning" answer taught me something new. Definitely worth posting, and I'll gladly let him boost for it. +1 for a question I should know more about but didn't realize.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A portfolio is a collection of your very best photographs. There are typically two modes for presenting a portfolio, namely online and prints. The use for them will depend on what you are wanting to use the portfolio, but let me give a few key pointers.

1. The portfolio probably should not consist of more than 10 pictures, at least for an initial portfolio. It can be okay to have a slightly larger portfolio if a prospective client wants to see more of your work.
2. It is more important to have consistently high quality of pictures than shear numbers. If a picture is not your very best, then don't include it. It's better to have 5 great photos than 5 great photos and 5 okay photos.
3. Make sure your portfolio consists of photographs that you want to sell to your client. Don't include dog shots in a wedding portfolio, or wedding pictures in a landscape portfolio. It can be okay to mix slightly, such as portraits and wedding, but you might consider having multiple portfolios even then.
4. If you print your portfolio, it is best to not bind the photographs.
5. If you are submitting a portfolio to a business, then find their standards for making a portfolio and follow them **exactly**!

Just to help hone in a few more points, I have 2 portfolios, one of landscape/wildlife, and a second of portraits, to which I am including links. I welcome any feedback as well on the portfolios, email me at ben@pearsonartphoto.com. [Portrait](http://www.pearsonartphoto.com/Professional/Packages/8369038_JhqkY#697978880_qDwrc), [Desert Photos](http://www.pearsonartphoto.com/Professional/Southwest-Desert-Photos-for/10070463_6xnnL#712011934_uHtJC)

Comment: +1 for quality vs. quantity. One of my mentors would always tell me that "if your picture requires *any* disclaimers, explanations, excuses, or you just don't think you'll be able to keep your big mouth shut about it for some reason, it doesn't belong in your portfolio." The work must be of a high enough quality that it both literally and metaphorically speaks for itself.

Comment: @JayLancePhotography: High praise from the master;-)

Comment: Oh jeez, I don't know about that. :-) It's a solid answer and it also means I don't have to write one myself. Win-win! :-)

Comment: *"That"* being whether or not I'm a 'master' at anything in particular. Just re-read my comment and thought it could really be taken the wrong way if I didn't clarify. :-)

Comment: @JayLancePhotography: LOL, I thought you were being sarcastic about not knowing about portfolios...

Comment: I do think its kind of funny that your linked portfolio breaks your #1 rule.

Comment: To be fair, it's not like he has 78 pictures in there, and he did indicate that it's OK to potentially have a *slightly* larger port depending on the client base. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Fine-art photographers  typically **create a 'portfolio' on some thematic ground** or other--in this context, the photographs in it might in some ways play a part in the whole rather than being the very best the photographer has taken. This is sort of like a writer approaches a book--a meditation of sorts on some 'topic' that unifies the images. I use quotes on 'topic' to indicate that sometimes the **unifying principle** of the portfolio **isn't always immediately or literally apparent**... i.e. some 'fine arts' portfolios may be more literal such as, for example, 'the children of war' or 'the cascade mountains' or whatever, but sometimes it might be much, much **harder to actually put into words what unifies the body of work** into a 'portfolio' and as such, it might not have a descriptive name (or, alternatively, a name that is somewhat obtuse or vague).

To me, these 'portfolios' where you see, say, 10 photographs and you can *feel* that they go together, but you can't easily articulate why, are the most interesting.  Photography is, um, a visual art, and as such, follows a logic that sometimes parallels the way verbal logic operates, but sometimes rolls on another level that would be reductive and inaccurate to verbalize--it has a different sort of logic. A portfolio as a somehow related set of images amplifies this concept: something in the unconsious tries to connect the dots and draw significance by marrying the photos together. **Sometimes this juxdisposition can lead to interesting conclusions greater than the sum of the parts.** In short, the portfolio can be an extension of photographic 'reasoning'.

**Another reason to make a portfolio is that it signals to the world that you are 'a serious photographer that serious people should seriously take seriously'** (and buy at a high price 'cos, you know, it's serious) .  By putting your work in an archival clamshell box you are telling the world you are a serious artist. It's just a sleight of hand that we all sorta fall for. For whatever reason, taking a photograph and [putting a mat on it](http://www.putabirdonit.com/) not only makes it look better, but it makes it more legitimate. It's sort of like publishing in journals if you are an academic. It's just something that shows you belong to a specific crowd of special seers, etc. Very much worth the price, nudge nuge. Pro film/video types have 'reels'. still-folks have 'portfolios'.

If we look back at the old masters (say Steglitz for arguments sake), it isn't that often when we even think in terms of 'portfolio'. now maybe image abc was part of a portfolio back in the day and maybe it wasn't. Who cares? On the other hand, I really like the 'portfolio' approach--it tells a story, it makes me think about the work taken as a whole, etc, on the other, it's just a silly (and stuffy) convention. However, having said that, Robert Frank's *The Americans* is an example of a portfolio that stands the test of time as a unified whole. I don't think of Frank's work in terms of individual photographs. I think of the portfolio.

Comment: +1 Great additional perspective on fine art portfolios...

Answer (score 2):

If your area of expertise is photojournalism, you need a portfolio too, but the requirements are a bit different. You'll want your best photographs, just like others have mentioned, however you'll 'submit' them in the form of what are called 'tearsheets.' This is literally when you tear your picture (and often the article) out and put it in a portfolio binder of some sort. The goal is a little different with a photojournalistic portfolio, you're looking for a job instead of trying to get hired for a contract, but the principle is similar.

Comment: One would hope that the publisher would offer you tearsheets that haven't literally been torn from the publication. That's what I used to get -- pristine pages that were never bound, neatly trimmed.